# I need to access ALL keys and ALL values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

So I've got this dictionary which sorts a text file. This text file is a list delimited by equal signs (i.e. Packagename = versionnumber).

After parsing the file:

```
mydict = {}
with open('security-updates.txt') as f: 
    for line in f.readlines():
        mykey, sep, myval = line.partition('=')
        mydict[mykey] = mykey
        mydict[myval] = myval
```

When I try to access `mydict[mykey]` it only returns the last *key* in the list. When I try to access `mydict[myval]` it only returns the last *value* in the list.  I need to be able to say "ALL 'mykey's" or "ALL 'myval's" in the dictionary. Is there a way to do this?

**UPDATED CODE**

```
mydict = {}
with open('chef-security-updates.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        mykey,sep,ver_val = line.partition('=')
        mydict[mykey] = myval

mydict.keys()
```

This is the entire block. I've figured out that I can't `print(mydict.keys())` for some reason, but when I set `mykeys = mydict.keys()` I can then print `mykeys`.  The print function was throwing a type error.  All seems to work now.  Cheers, everyone for helping me.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do... Why don't you just store `mydict[mykey] = myval` and then extract all keys and values from it using `mydict.keys()` and `mydict.values()`?

Comment: Do you have any duplicate keys or values (I'd imagine not in keys, but what about values)? If so, you'll overwrite fields in your dict. Also, are you actually running `mydict[mykey]`? If so, is `mykey` still set to the last value from the loop? Also, stanleyli has a good point about your use of a dictionary.

Comment: @stanleyli I tried that, but I'm getting an "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_keys' and 'str'" error.  All I did was change code to 'medicate[mykey] = myval' and underneath, I added a print statement to print the keys. ( print(mydict.keys()) )

Comment: @jalyper Please paste your code.

Comment: @jalyper The name of the dict seems different in your code. Maybe you want to edit your question and paste the complete code?

Comment: @stanleyli see updated question/code.  I think the print function was giving me trouble.  Thanks for helping me out

Comment: @jalyper There is no reason that you can't print `mydict.keys()`. It is just a normal list. In python almost everything can be printed as long as it has `__str__` or `__repr__`. If you are using Python 2.x, you need to use `print mydict.keys()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the dictionary wrong. It should be like:

```
mydict = {}
with open('security-updates.txt') as f: 
    for line in f.readlines():
        mykey, sep, myval = line.partition('=')
        mydict[mykey] = myval
mydict.keys()           # all the keys of the dict
mydict.values()         # all the values of the dict
```